# How to update TextBlock text inside of ListBox item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

So I have a simple UDP chat app from a WinForm project, which I wanted to look a little bit better, so I am re-making it in WPF. As I realized I can easily put 2 or more TextBlocks inside of a ListItem, I wanted to display the last message of each chat, like so:

[image: Last message...]

But I have no Idea on how to edit those TextBlocks :( I literary just started with WPF, so I bet I just made a duplicate, but because of that, I don't even know how to search for this issue.

Here is the custom ListBox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="myList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="264" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" BorderThickness="0,1,1,0" MouseLeftButtonUp="myList_MouseLeftButtonUp" Margin="0,25,0,0">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Width="250">
                    <DockPanel Margin="0,7">
                        <Ellipse Name="ellipse" Margin="5"  DockPanel.Dock="Left" Style="{DynamicResource elstyle}">
                        </Ellipse>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0,0,0,7" FontWeight="Bold" MaxWidth="250"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Visibility="Hidden" FontSize="1.333"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="last_message" Text="{Binding LastMessage}" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" MaxWidth="250"></TextBlock>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"how to address those TextBlocks"_? Your `TextBlocks` look fine. What does your item view model look like? Does it have **public** `Name`, `ID` and `LastMessage` **properties**?

Comment: Sorry, I meant on how to edit them. I would like to insert the last message every time the client receives one. For example something like this: `ListBox.Items[0].last_message.text = "Hi, this is Zalma";`

Comment: You don't edit them. You change bound `LastMessage` property in your view model and if that raises [`INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event it will be picked up by UI and `TextBlock` will be refreshed. How does your view model class look like?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what is the View Model

Comment: It's a class behind each item. I'm guessing you set `myList.ItemsSource` to some implementation of `IEnumerable<MyItem>` where `MyItem` is your view model and should have `Name`, `ID` and `LastMessage` properties. If not how do you populate your list?

Comment: I populate it like this: `myList.Items.Add(new { Name = words[0], ID = words[2], LastMessage = "LastMessage..." });`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106814/discussion-between-caddaile-and-dkozl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is simplified model to show the principal** but if you would create view model class that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to hold your item data

```
public class MyItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;

    private string _id;

    private string _lastMessage;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public string ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }

    public string LastMessage
    {
        get { return _lastMessage; }
        set
        {
            _lastMessage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LastMessage");
        }
    }
}
```

and then in your window

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<MyItem> _myItems = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myList.ItemsSource = _myItems;
        _myItems.Add(new MyItem { Name = "name", ID = "id", LastMessage = "last message" });
        _myItems[0].LastMessage = "new message";
    }
}
```

and then you don't operate on `myList` control anymore but on `_myItems` list and its items. If you add/remove item in the collection it will add/remove item in the UI, if you change property of an item it will update bound property in the UI

Comment: It will also work both ways so if for example you would have `TextBox` instead of `TextBlock` and allow users to edit `Name` for example UI would automatically update bound property in your view model.